# Best way to delete elements from two arrays using delete_if

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was wondering if this can be improved upon.

I have two arrays: links and archived_releases.
`links` contains strings, that might appear in the :url key
of an `archived_releases` entry.

This didn't work:

```
links.delete_if { |link|
  archived_releases.count > archived_releases.delete_if{ |release| release[:url] == link }.count
}
```

So I came up with this:

```
links.delete_if { |link|
  archived_releases.count > archived_releases.delete_if{ |release| release[:url] == link }.count
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first pull out the `archived_releases` entries you want to quickly compare and then you can just use a quick `include?` check. Something like:

```
urls = archived_releases.collect { |ar| ar[:url] }
links.delete_if { |link| urls.include?(link) }
```